# How to show in PDF template the field date in orbeon without "/"

Tags: pdf, acrobat, orbeon

I need to generate a PDF template acrobat from XHTML of Orbeon, so when I have a date field in the template PDF, I can't show the whole date because I have in the template 8 cases but in orbeon 10 cases: example for the field date 12/08/2016 in orbeon => in the pdf template is shown like 12 /0 8/20, I try to write a script in Acrobat but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Orbeon Forms used to have a way to specify the formats, but somehow this seems to have been removed. See [this issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/148) for details.

At this moment I am not sure there is a workaround until this issue is addressed in the Orbeon Forms code base.